# Understand OkHttp publicsuffixes.gz

Tags: android, okhttp

I'm doing a small Android Application, currently the apk has 382KB, and I'm using OkHttp, looking inside the apk, the Okhttp inserts a file [publicsuffixes.gz](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/resources/okhttp3/internal/publicsuffix/publicsuffixes.gz) that has 33Kb (8~9% of total apk size).

If I exclude the file with the follow code the application crashes, so it obviously necessary, my question is, what is the function of that file and is it possible to replace or modify to reduce the size?

The exclude code:

```
android {
    ...
    packagingOptions {
        exclude "publicsuffixes.gz"
    }
}
```

Comment: see here for some more info https://publicsuffix.org/list/ it can be to be used to block cookies for one of these domains.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51720114/strange-error-with-glide-while-loading-image-on-production-build/53479414#53479414

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, this shouldn't fail if you don't configure your client to support cookies.  Can you provide a stacktrace of it failing?

If you need cookies but don't care about security (YOLO!) I suspect you could hack something up by modifying https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/9bfe575960af8e7bb164642f2f513b5ccb39ff4f/okhttp/src/test/java/okhttp3/internal/publicsuffix/PublicSuffixListGenerator.java

To have a basically empty file.  It seems like a bad idea, but caveat emptor.  You will break security around Cookie handling, which may or may not be acceptable to you.

Comment: Without it, a malicious site like `www.evil.co.uk` could set a cookie for `www.bank.co.uk`. This is because the public suffixes file is what tells OkHttp that `co.uk` isn’t a private domain.

Comment: My knowledge about network is limited, my use of okhttp is just access an API nothing more, do not look dangerous to me to remove once I'll not open sites or something like that, do you see an obvious problem by removing it?

Comment: If you don't care about cookies and have the default CookieJar.NO_COOKIES, then it shouldn't be failing.  So maybe start with that, and include a stack trace of where it fails.

Comment: @JesseWilson `www.evil.co.uk` redirect me to the twitter account of Donald Trump.

Answer (score 0):

in case if someone is facing HTTP FAILED: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load publicsuffixes.gz resource from the classpath issue , below given solution will work for them.

Add the following two lines to proguard-rules.pro

-keep class okhttp3.internal.publicsuffix.PublicSuffixDatabase
-keepnames class okhttp3.internal.publicsuffix.PublicSuffixDatabase

https://programmersought.com/article/25321169177/;jsessionid=A144F66609278A032E652302EB65AA95

Comment: You would probably want to add this one too-keep class 
```-keep class okhttp3.**{*;}```